# Cannot ssh to the ubuntu droplet from osx

Tags: macos, ssh, digital-ocean

I am trying to create a droplet on digital ocean with my public ssh key, droplet starts up fine, but than I cannot ssh to it. it prompts me for the password.

I went to the ubuntu server console trough digital ocean and looked at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and I see my public key.

This is the output of ssh {server_ip} -v command:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to {server_ip} [{server_ip}] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 45.55.2.137:22 as '{myuser}'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:FiZC1ldiqmwS4n5Z9mayVv2SpjdPbpVAqMwuGrBTbr8
debug1: Host '45.55.2.137' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/{myuser}/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the "ls -la" output for your .ssh directory on the remote system?

Comment: added it to the post

Comment: You are trying to log into the remote system as root? In the server's _sshd_config_ file, what is "PermitRootLogin" set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are authenticating as a `{myuser}` and you are showing us a home folder of `root`. It is not clear what you want to achieve, but there are two possibilities:

1. You want to authenticate as `{myuser}` and then you need to copy the `authorized_keys` to the appropriate home directory (`/home/{myuser}/.ssh/`) and fix the ovnership.
2. You want to authenticate as a root and then you should use:

   ```
   ssh -v root@{server_ip}
   ```

   but make sure you have root login allowed (`PermitRootLogin` option in `sshd_config`)! And note that it is not recommended setup.

Comment: You are right, I did know what I was doing. I should have used  ssh  root@{servier_ip}